# SwiftUI - How to pass date string from datepicker back to view model

Tags: mvvm, swiftui

### What I'm looking to accomplish

I have a view that represents a datepicker and another view that represents a list of workout classes for a particular day. I'd like to update the list of workouts when a user changes the date in the datepicker view. I'm following a MVVM design where I'm essentially looking to hold state (date string and list of workouts pertaining to that date) within my view model and pass it to my views.

I'd like to start with just updating my `stateDate` variable in my view model when the user picks a new date via the date picker and have it populate that string in another view. The end goal would be update the path in Firestore that I'm pulling data from, so I can pull in new data.

**How do I update a @Published variable in a view model when a user selects a new date via date picker in one of my views?**

### Source Snippets

**WorkoutDatePicker View**

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct WorkoutDatePicker: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = WorkoutClassViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            DatePicker("Date",
                       selection: $viewModel.stateDate,
                       displayedComponents: [.date])
            Text("Your current date is \(viewModel.stateDate)")
        }   
    }
}
```

**WorkoutClassViewModel ViewModel**

```swift
import Foundation
import FirebaseFirestore

class WorkoutClassViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var workoutClasses = [WorkoutClass]()
    @Published var stateDate = Date()
    
    private var db = Firestore.firestore()
    
    func fetchData() {
//        let dateString = getDateString(date: userData.date,format: "MM-dd-YYYY")
//        db.collection("schedules/\(dateString)/classes").addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
        db.collection("schedules/2021-07-18/classes").addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
            guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
                print("No documents")
                return
            }
            
            self.workoutClasses = documents.map { (queryDocumentSnapshot) -> WorkoutClass in
                let data = queryDocumentSnapshot.data()
                let id = queryDocumentSnapshot.documentID
                let reservationCnt = data["reservationCnt"] as? Int ?? 0
                let workoutType = data["workoutType"] as? String ?? ""
                return WorkoutClass(id: id, reservationCnt: reservationCnt,  workoutType: workoutType)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**ClassView View**

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ClassView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = WorkoutClassViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            WorkoutDatePicker()
            
            NavigationView {
                List(viewModel.workoutClasses) { workoutClass in
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        Text(workoutClass.workoutType).font(.title)
                    }
                }.onAppear() {
                    self.viewModel.fetchData()
                }
            }
        }    
    }
}
```

I'm new to SwiftUI and iOS development, so any advice is good advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now, you have two different instances of `WorkoutClassViewModel`. When one gets updated, the other doesn't know that the date has changed. To solve this, you can share the same `WorkoutClassViewModel` by passing a reference to the child view (`WorkoutDatePicker`). This is illustrated in another answer on this question.

Another option, which separates the responsibility of the child view to just picking the date, would be to pass a `@Binding` to *just* the `stateDate` that the child view can use:

```
struct WorkoutDatePicker: View {
    @Binding var date : Date //<-- Here
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            DatePicker("Date",
                       selection: $date,
                       displayedComponents: [.date])
            Text("Your current date is \(date)")
        }
    }
}

struct ClassView: View {
    @StateObject private var viewModel = WorkoutClassViewModel() //<-- Here
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            WorkoutDatePicker(date: $viewModel.stateDate)
            Text("Date: \(viewModel.stateDate)")
            
            NavigationView {
                List(viewModel.workoutClasses) { workoutClass in
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        Text(workoutClass.workoutType).font(.title)
                    }
                }.onAppear() {
                    self.viewModel.fetchData()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I implemented your suggested changes! After that, I was able to get the Firestore data to update when the date changes by adding the following after onAppear()

```
.onChange(of: viewModel.stateDate, perform: { value in
                                self.viewModel.fetchData()
                            })
```

I could still make this cleaner, but this has been a huge help to getting this functionality going, Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

try these source snippets:

```
class WorkoutClassViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var workoutClasses = [WorkoutClass]()
    @Published var stateDate = Date()
    
    private var db = Firestore.firestore()
    
    func fetchData(completion: @escaping (WorkoutClass?) -> Void) {  // <--- here
//        let dateString = getDateString(date: userData.date,format: "MM-dd-YYYY")
//        db.collection("schedules/\(dateString)/classes").addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
        db.collection("schedules/2021-07-18/classes").addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
            guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
                print("No documents")
                completion(nil) // <--- here
                return
            }
            
            self.workoutClasses = documents.map { (queryDocumentSnapshot) -> WorkoutClass in
                let data = queryDocumentSnapshot.data()
                let id = queryDocumentSnapshot.documentID
                let reservationCnt = data["reservationCnt"] as? Int ?? 0
                let workoutType = data["workoutType"] as? String ?? ""
                // --- here
                completion(WorkoutClass(id: id, reservationCnt: reservationCnt,  workoutType: workoutType))
            }
        }
    }
    

}
struct ClassView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = WorkoutClassViewModel() // <--- here
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            WorkoutDatePicker(viewModel: viewModel)  // <--- here
            
            NavigationView {
                List(viewModel.workoutClasses) { workoutClass in
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        Text(workoutClass.workoutType).font(.title)
                    }
                }.onAppear() {
                    self.viewModel.fetchData()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
struct WorkoutDatePicker: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: WorkoutClassViewModel  // <--- here
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            DatePicker("Date",
                       selection: $viewModel.stateDate,
                       displayedComponents: [.date])
            Text("Your current date is \(viewModel.stateDate)")
        }
    }
}
```